# Store fullfile in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I store all the fullfileName generated in this code in one cell?

Code:

```
for k = 1:length(allFiles)
    baseFileName = allFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(handles.sourceFolder, baseFileName);
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Use cell array? Something like - `fullFileName{k} = fullfile(handles.sourceFolder, baseFileName)`?

Comment: And don't forget to preallocate that cell array: `fullFileName = cell(1,length(allFiles))`

Answer (score 0):

Create a nested cell array:

```
my_cell_array = cell(1);
my_cell_array{1} = cell(length(allFiles),1);
```

Then create a structure into a cell in your cell array:

```
for k = 1:length(allFiles)
    baseFileName = allFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(handles.sourceFolder, baseFileName);
    my_cell_array{1}{k} = fullFileName
end
```

Then you can access each element as follows

```
disp(my_cell_array{1}{k})
```